# mount to nfs server failed, system error: no route to host

Tags: linux, networking, nfs

I have fedora based linux machines in a closed network. In one of the lab machines, I am getting the below error.

```
Mount to NFS server failed. System error: No route to host
```

I restarted the **nfs**, **nfslock** and **portmap** services. I restarted the **iptables** service. I also disabled the **iptables** service and restarted the machine. I compared the contents of the below files from another perfectly working client.

```
/etc/hosts.allow 
/etc/sysconfig/iptables
/etc/fstab
```

ping/ssh from the affected machine to the server and other clients is working fine. `rpcinfo -p` gives the same output as I get in the other client machines.

Comment: Are you able to telnet/ping/traceroute to the NFS server?

Comment: Refer this link for `No route to the host issue` http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/no-route-to-host-error-and-solution.html

Comment: All the commands mentioned in the link seem to be working fine. Also, am able to telnet/ping/traceroute to the NFS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the command `service autofs restart` once the system booted. I was able to login as the LDAP user with the user's home directory getting mounted from the centralized server. I believe when the system was booting, the NFS was not ready and that is the reason I was getting mount to NFS server failed.